# Change (replace) <b> tags to <strong> tags

Tags: javascript, tags

Wanted to change / replace all my "b" tags ~ bold tags to "strong" tags in wordpress.

I used some snippets to achieve it but they are not making them work.

Snippets used,

#First

```
function change_b_to_strong($content){
    str_replace('<b>', '<strong>', $content);
    str_replace('</b>', '</strong>', $content);
    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'change_b_to_strong' );
```

#Second

```
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'modify_formats');

function modify_formats($settings){
   $formats = array(
     'bold' => array('inline' => 'b'),
     'strong' => array('inline' => 'strong')
    );
    $settings['formats'] = json_encode( $formats );
    return $settings;
}
```

Comment: Those are both PHP. Where did you use them?

Comment: @JacobPeattie used in functions.php as well as other snippet plugins like code snippets etc

Comment: In the first snippet, you did not save the modified `$content` value back to that variable. I.e. You should do `$content = str_replace( ... )`.

Comment: @SallyCJ i dont want to save them to DB just wanted to display at #CodeView #ViewSource

Comment: `the_content` is a filter hook applied when displaying the post, not when saving it into the database.

Comment: well the above works for me at my localhost but at live the theme is creating <b> tags and still they are showing the same. @JacobPeattie

Comment: If your theme has `<b>` tags hardcoded into your templates you're not going to be able to replace them with a filter. You'll need to replace the templates via a child theme.

Comment: @JacobPeattie my theme automatically creates <b> tag whenever we create / use any heading tags like h1 h2 it creates <b> tag and i was trying to replace them.

Comment: any possibilities of removing <b> tags in wordpress ?

Comment: Use heading tags where? Are you using the classic editor or the block editor, or a page builder like Elementor or Visual Composer/WP Bakery?

Comment: actually theme has its own editor named UX builder (UX blocks) we use Total theme. https://docs.uxthemes.com/article/237-ux-builder-how-to-use-blocks

Comment: You're going to need to speak to the author then. That would be off topic here.

Comment: If the <b>s are generated by the theme template then they won't be covered by the_content() filter, no. You'd have to modify the theme.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sally CJ mentioned, you should set a result of `str_replace()` to a variable.
For a content you chose a right filter - `the_content`, for tinymce editor you need to use `the_editor` filter. 
As they a similar, you can use one function for both filters. 
In my example I use only one str_replace for opening and closing tags.
Basically, it will be enough, unless you have 'b>' text in your content to.

```
function change_b_to_strong($content){
    $content = str_replace('b>', 'strong>', $content);
    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'change_b_to_strong' );
add_filter( 'the_editor', 'change_b_to_strong' );
```

### Update

If you output content using `get_the_content` for example, this filter will never fire. 
You can apply `the_content` filter to your text also.

```
$content = get_the_content();
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
```

Comment: Really nice! never thought about doing `'b>', 'strong>'`, great way to save php resources and writing cleaner code!

Comment: well the above works for me at my localhost but at live the theme is creating <b> tags and still they are showing the same. @anton

Comment: These filters allows to manipulate with output html as they are last in a chain of hooks. Don't think it depends on a server. Which hook exactly do not work? For example if you use `get_the_content` to get a content, `the_content` filter for this will not fire. Add more info to your question about this and I'll try to edit my answer.

Comment: [Obligatory: you can't parse HTML with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454). (I know this is not regex, but the same applies - XML parser would be the better choice.)

Comment: @kero Why it's better?

Comment: @anton The linked answer should explain. Basically now you're just replacing some strings - without understanding any of the logic. What about "<foob>"? Will get replaced through "<foostrong>" with your code.

Comment: of course it will replace any "b>" in code, that's why I wrote "in my example I use..."

Comment: Doesn't work when i test it.